# Handling RxJava subscriptions on Android elegantly?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, reactivex

Is there an elegant way of handling RxJava subscriptions when dealing with Android state changes (like orientation change) or async platform events (like push notification events) etc.?

I've been using an EventBus for handling things like this so far and would like to move over to RxJava completely if possible (without the need for an EventBus), but somehow the EventBus architecture seems a lot nicer (just register and unregister as needed) for handling these scenarios, especially when dealing with Android platform events.

With RxJava alone it seems we still need a way of persisting the subscriptions beyond the lifecycle of the fragment / activity (either with **Loaders**, **Retained fragments**, **Application cache** etc. are there any others?) all of which seem to feel like quite a bit of extra work and handling.

Comment: how does event bus solve it elegantly?

Answer (score 0):

Use [CompositeSubscription](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subscriptions/CompositeSubscription.html)

Here some example:

```
private CompositeSubscription subscriptions = new CompositeSubscrition();

public void someSubscribe() {
    subscriptions.add(Observable.just(null).subscribe(someNull -> doSmth())
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    subscriptions.clear() //Here all subscriptions, that were added to composite subscription, will unsubscribe
    super.onPause()
}
```

Comment: I don't think CompositeSubscriptions are lifecycle aware are they? Or could you please explain how they work in the scenarios mentioned above (async events or config changes etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute EventBus with Bus-on-RX. Then you have to use singleton Subjects to publish events. In that case you don't need to retain subscriptions, because Subjects are "hot" Observables. It means that you can subscribe to/unsubscribe from it anytime and it will still be able to produce events. What happens at the moment of the (re)subscription is determined by [Subject type](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html).

If you want to get away from event-bus-driven-architecture completely, then accept the fact that there is no "silver bullet" to retain Observables (or any other objects) between configuration changes. You can use retained Fragments, Loaders, retained Presenters, singletons, some libraries and so on. It depends on a particular case and your personal preferences.